# Problema unsigned char no imprime valor

Tags: c++

Tengo que ingresar valores a y b a unas variables unsigned char pero no termino de entender bien el unsigned mi codigo es este:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

   unsigned char a[5],b[4];

    cout<<"Ingresa A: "; cin>>a;
    cout<<"Ingresa B: "; cin>>b;

    cout<<"A:"<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"B:"<<b<<endl;

     return 0;
    }
```

y el error que me da es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ingreso a y b pero a no lo imprime, y si reviso a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfAQ6.png) por ejemplo existe pero a[0] no
No se que mas hacer :c

Comment: Es necesario que declares tus variables como unsigned char? No pueden se rde tipo char solo?

Comment: @Kate505 declaradas como `char` también pasa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existe ninguna sobrecarga del [operador de lectura desde flujo de datos (`>>`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) que acepte formaciones de caracteres:

```
basic_istream& operator>>( short& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned short& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( int& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned int& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( long& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned long& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( long long& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned long long& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( float& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( double& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( long double& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( bool& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( void*& value );
basic_istream& operator>>( std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );
basic_istream& operator>>( std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );
basic_istream& operator>>( basic_istream& (*func)(basic_istream&) );
basic_istream& operator>>( std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>* sb );
```

Así que la lectura decae a la versión del operador que lee sobre un puntero.

Cuando leemos desde la consola (*`c`onsole `in`put*) y pasamos un puntero, se leerá hasta finalizar la línea, así que con esta entrada:

> ```
> 1010
> 1010
> ```

En el búfer de datos tenemos:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `'1'` | `'0'` | `'1'` | `'0'` | `'\n'` | `'1'` | `'0'` | `'1'` | `'0'` | `'\n'` |

Se leen cinco bytes (desde el primer carácter hasta el salto de línea) sobre la primera variable y después otros cinco en la segunda variable, como el dato sobre el que se lee ha decaído a puntero se pierde la información de tamaño y no se hacen comprobaciones de límites, no pasaría nada salvo por el detalle de que una de las variables no tiene cinco elementos si no cuatro:

```
unsigned char a[5],b[4];
//                   ^ <--- Oh, ¡rempámpanos!
```

Escribir en elementos fuera de una formación es comportamiento indefinido, así que podría haber pasado cualquier cosa pero lo que *creo* que ha pasado en este caso es lo siguiente:

1. Las formaciones `a` y `b` están en memoria distribuidas en orden inverso a la definición:

   ```
   unsigned char a[5],b[4];
   ```

   | `b[0]` | `b[1]` | `b[2]` | `b[3]` | `a[0]` | `a[1]` | `a[2]` | `a[3]` | `a[4]` |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
2. Al leer sobre la formación `a` todo funciona correctamente:

   | `b[0]` | `b[1]` | `b[2]` | `b[3]` | `a[0]` | `a[1]` | `a[2]` | `a[3]` | `a[4]` |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   |  |  |  |  | `'1'` | `'0'` | `'1'` | `'0'` | `0` |

   En la última posición se guarda el carácter nulo (`0`) indicando el final de cadena.
3. Al leer sobre la formación `b` se sobrescribe el primer carácter de la formación `a`:

   | `b[0]` | `b[1]` | `b[2]` | `b[3]` | `a[0]` | `a[1]` | `a[2]` | `a[3]` | `a[4]` |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | `'1'` | `'0'` | `'1'` | `'0'` | `0` ¡sobrescrito! | `'0'` | `'1'` | `'0'` | `0` |

   En la última posición se guarda el carácter nulo (`0`) indicando el final de cadena.
4. Al imprimir, como la formación `a` empieza por el carácter nulo (`0`) se considera que la cadena esta vacía.

---

Podemos comprobar que esto es lo que sucede si imprimimos el contenido como número:

```
for (const auto &c : a) cout << int(c) << '\t'; cout << '\n';
for (const auto &c : b) cout << int(c) << '\t'; cout << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 0 48  49  48  0   
> 49    48  49  48
> ```

Otra prueba de ello es que cambiando el orden de definición (`unsigned char b[4],a[5];`) el problema no sucede; tampoco sucede si ambas formaciones tienen el tamaño suficiente para almacenar todos los caracteres (`unsigned char a[5],b[5];`).